Scrolling Issue on Mobile Devices
There seems to be an issue with the scrolling when opening the modern pages on SharePoint Subscription edition.
Replication steps

Navigate to a Modern Team Site
Create a sample modern page
The page should be long, with 8-14 webparts. Ideally, use Hero webparts, quick links, images, etc.
Save the page.
Open the page using a mobile browser. Android or iPhone. It does not matter

Expected result
The page should be scrollable within a second or so
Actual result
The page is not scrollable until 5-20 seconds later.
As a test, I opened several large, complex Modern pages on SharePoint Online and this issue it's not happening: I can scroll right away.
Question

Is there a way to make the page scrollable right away, without waiting for up to 20 seconds?

